# HOw to put output value in mysql function and return it

Tags: mysql, function

I'm having some trouble with the following problem:

```
delimiter //
create function geefPrijsVoorVlucht(FID INT, CID INT)
RETURNS INT(11)
begin
SELECT CurrPrice
into @prijs
FROM stats
where FlightID = FID and ClassID = CID;
return @prijs;
end //
delimiter ;

call geefPrijsVoorVlucht(652, 2);
```

It doesn't produce a return value, nor an error which I can base myself on.
I'm probebly assigning and returning the values the wrong way.

Btw I'm very new to Mysql, so please don't shoot me! 
Can anywone see whatn I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: `call` is for procedures. But you've defined a function. Try `select geefPrijsVoorVlucht(652, 2)`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel you are right,my mistake. But It doesn't do much eighter